# Asp.Net MVC DateTime culture issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, culture

I am trying to show Month and year instead of Date in control on UI. Will this be a issue  for the date if I do not specify culture explicitly. Will this break if server locale is changed? How do I manage in this case? What will be the better way to write the below code ?

```
[DisplayName("Delivery Month")]
public string DeliveryMonth
{
    get
    {
        return DeliveryDate.ToString("Y");
    }
    set
    {
        DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse("1." + this.DeliveryMonth);
    }
}

public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: How are you displaying it? You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DeliveryDate, "{0:MM-yyyy}"), but it wont be bound on post back. You would need to create a custom `ModelBinder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, you can set the DeliveryDate as string

```
public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }
```

Then in your view. you can add a textbox for your model that will turn into a datetimepicker control, through the use of jQuery.

The html for the textbox:

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DeliveryDate,
    new { @class = "DeliveryDatePicker", style =  "width:50%;height:25px;background:transparent;padding:0;margin-left:5px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryDate)
</div>
```

The jQuery to be placed in the document load function:

```
$("#DeliveryDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

The format of the datepicker - you can set it to whatever format you need - just moth and year in your case by using dateFormat(now.getMonth() + 1) and dateFormat(now.getYear() - 100) functions. e.g. to set it to the full date in jQuery it would be:

```
$("#DeliveryDate").val(dateFormat(now.getDate()) + '/' + dateFormat(now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dateFormat(now.getYear() - 100));
```

In your data access/repository get method, you will need to get it as string:

```
deliveryModel.DeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataReader["DELIVERYDATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
```

And when you post the update, convert it to datetime in your data access method:

```
SqlParameter sqlParameter1 = sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryDate", Convert.ToDateTime(deliveryModel.DeliveryDate));
```